# Sending data from html to python

Tags: pi-3, python-3, html5

I'm doing a project called IoT based announcement system where the user has to type the lcd number and the information to be announced in a webpage and that data should be printed and also converted in text to speech form in the LCD and speakers interfaced to the raspberry pi. I have currently created a webpage and send those data to a database. Can anyone tell me how to send those data to the raspberry pi?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to do some research to identify a reasonable solution.  When you have that you should ask a more targeted, less broad, question.  At the moment it seems like you want to get design help on the cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For, sending data from the web to the raspberry. You can use socket's, by using socket programming you can send your data from client to server.

You can refer socket details from below site.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html